# How do i change the color of the placeholder text in an input type="text" if a certain value is submitted?

Tags: javascript, html, css, input, placeholder

I've got a bar in which a user can type in an adress. If an invalid adress is given the typed in texed gets removed and the placeholder text gets changed to "Adress not found". I also want the placeholder text to become red but i cant quite figure out how.

this is the code in the index

```
<input type="text" id="searchAdress" placeholder="Type an adress, city or country" />
```

this is the code in the js

```
if (data.length > 0){
            document.getElementById("searchAdress").value='';
            document.getElementById("searchAdress").placeholder = "Type an adress, city or country";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("searchAdress").value='';
            document.getElementById("searchAdress").placeholder = "Adress not found";
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally in CSS you would use the `::placeholder` selector to modify placeholder color. In JavaScript, you can't really modify CSS pseudo selectors, so you'll have to assign a specific class to each placeholder color like so:

```js
var input = document.getElementById("searchAdress");
function validate(){
  var value = input.value;
  if(value.length>0){
    //Valid
    input.value="";
    input.placeholder="Got it";
    clearOtherClasses(input);
    input.classList.add("green");
  }else{
    //Invalid
    input.value="";
    input.placeholder="Nope";
    clearOtherClasses(input);
    input.classList.add("red");
  }
}
function clearOtherClasses(element){
  element.className="";
}
```

```css
.green::placeholder{
  color:green;
}
.red::placeholder{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<input  type="text" id="searchAdress" placeholder="Type an adress, city or country"><button onclick="validate()">validate</button>
<hr>
Enter nothing to toggle red placeholder text. Enter something to toggle green.
```

The function `clearOtherClasses()` is used to prevent conflicting color classes (e.g, an input has both the `green` class and the `red` class).